# cljs Om interop with React components?

Tags: javascript, clojure, reactjs, clojurescript, om

Is it possible to use third-party React components in an Om application?

I have a project written in ClojureScript with Om and I would like to use [JedWatson/react-select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select), how should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few steps to this:

- Packaging the JS library for use in Clojurescript
  JS libaries are packages as `foreign-libraries` you can read more about this [in the ClojureScript wiki](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Packaging-Foreign-Dependencies).
- after you required your foreign lib you can access it though the global namespace (`js/`) and call functions defined by your library.

Here is an [example of using `fixed-data-table` with Om](https://github.com/ul/fixed-data-table-demo).

The packaged foreign library for it can be found in the [CLJSJS packages repository](https://github.com/cljsjs/packages/tree/master/fixed-data-table). (More information about CLJSJS can be found on the website: http://cljsjs.github.io/)

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to bundle in library's CSS in a similar fashion?

Comment: Could you please explain the packaging process in a bit more details. Do I need to create an uberjar via `lein uberjar` or it's not necessary? Also, what is supposed to go in `externs.js`? It's not quite clear from the wiki

Comment: In addition: This is pretty cool: http://mneise.github.io/posts/2015-08-04-week-9-and-10.html

Comment: There is a wiki page on using [non JS assets](https://github.com/cljsjs/packages/wiki/Non-JS-Assets) in the CLJSJS wiki but it presumes [boot](http://boot-clj.com/) and is in general a bit more manual.